# Confusion about domain of definition for rational functions

Tags: real-analysis, definition

Many times I get confused about the domain of function when we deal with limit or continuity or differentiation at particular point. I want to get clear about this confusion.

From baby rudin.

In definition $5.1$, to define derivative of real valued $f$, it is first assured that $f$ is defined on $[a,b]$ and then derivative is defined for $x\in [a,b]$.

Theorem $5.3$ part (c) says, Suppose $f$ and $g$ are defined on $[a,b]$ and are differentiable at point $x\in [a,b]$, then $(\frac{f}{g})'(x)=\frac{g(x)f'(x)-g'(x)f(x)}{g(x)^2}$, provided $g(x)\neq 0$.

Here's my doubt : When we define $\frac{f}{g}$, we alter the domain by removing those points at which $g$ takes value $0$. Then, it is possible that the alterted domain for $\frac{f}{g}$ may not be even interval. Then how to define derivative? I think along with assumption $g(x)\neq 0$, we should put one more assumption that in some neighbourhood of $x$, $g$ doesn't take value $0$.

Such kind of confusion pops up many times in my mind. For simplicity, can I always make the assumption that given function(even if rational) is nicely defined in some neighbourhood of point $p$, (i.e. when domain is real, function makes sense for $(a,b)$ and $p\in (a,b)$), at which we wish to determine continuity/differentiability/limit.

Comment: Think about trigonometric functions: let $f(x) = \operatorname{sin}(x), g(x) = \operatorname{cos}(x)$, what can you say about the derivative of the function $h(x) = \operatorname{tan}(x)$ at $x = \frac{\pi}{2}$?

Comment: The function $g$ is differentiable at $x$, thus continuous at $x$, and $g(x) \ne 0$.  Therefore there is an open neighborhood of $x$ with $g \ne 0$ on that neighborhood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you missed the sentence that appears right before theorem 5.2:

> If $f$ is defined on a segment $(a,b)$ and if $a<x<b$, then $f'(x)$ is defined […] as above. But $f'(a)$ and $f'(b)$ are not defined in this case.

So, consider, say, $f,g\colon[0,1]\longrightarrow\Bbb R$ defined by $f(x)=x$ and by $g(x)=2x-1$ respectively. Then the domain of $\frac fg$ is $\left[0,\frac12\right)\cup\left(\frac12,1\right]$. In particular, the domain of $\frac fg$ contains both intervals $\left(0,\frac12\right)$ and $\left(\frac12,1\right)$, and therefore it makes sense to talk about $\left(\frac fg\right)'$ when $x$ belongs to any of these intervals.

Comment: Ok.. so even if we remove points at which $g$ vanishes, the domain for $f/g$  will still be countable collection of disjoint intervals or segments, and then we can stick to that particular interval or segment where our point of interest lies. Am I correct?

Comment: In some cases, the set of points at which $g$ vanishes can be uncountable. But what matters here is that if $g(x_0)\ne0$, then there is an interval around $x_0$ in which all goes well.

Comment: one small doubt. Can this will happen that in the altered domain for $f/g$, we have isolated point? I guess no. Differentiability in turn continuityof $g$, will give $g(x)=0$ at that isolated point. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Sir sorry but one last thing..  looking again at Rudin's definition 5.1 for derivative.. I guess we don't need the assumption that $f$ to be defined on $[a,b]$. Instead we can say, $f:E \subset R \to R$ and take $x\in E$ such that $x$ is limit point of $E$, and then continue as author did. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, except the $x$ must also be an element of $E$.

Comment: Thank you ....!

Answer (score 0):

The derivative of a function is defined from a limit. You need to use the rules that hold for limits. In particular, you only use the values where the function is defined, i.e you remain in the domain of the fuction. So if there are zero denominators, you can still compute the limit and see if the derivative exists.